# USING IF Statement with FORTH produces "Interpreting a compile-only word"

Tags: if-statement, forth, gforth

I'm reading [*Starting Forth: 4. Decisions, Decisions...*](https://www.forth.com/starting-forth/4-conditional-if-then-statements/). I can run `42 42 = .`

```
42 42 =  ok
42 42 = . -1  ok
```

Predictably, I get `-1` which is [two's compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for `true`. However, if I push a `42` on the stack, and I run

```
42 .s
42 = IF ." foobar " THEN ;
```

I would expect `foobar` to be outputted and it's not. Instead I get

```
    42 .s <1> 42  ok
    42 = IF ." foobar " THEN ;  
:2: Interpreting a compile-only word
    42 = >>>IF<<< ." foobar " THEN ; 
Backtrace:
$7F7539250B30 throw
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe these must be compiled into words, for whatever reasons expressions aren't primitives. I believe this is referenced in the book with,

> Notice: an `IF…THEN` statement must be contained within a definition. You can’t just enter these words in “calculator style.”

So it would look like this,

```
: mycond 42 = IF ." foobar " THEN ;   ok
42 .s <1> 42  ok
mycond foobar  ok
42 mycond foobar  ok
```

This is again in the [gforth docs on Conditional execution](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Conditional-execution-Tutorial.html#Conditional-execution-Tutorial)

> In Forth you can use control structures only inside colon definitions. An if-structure looks like this:

Answer (score 1):

Exactly structured words are compiled word usage only
for loops / if / while...until & so on....

Use Gforth documentation only. This is the best one. I mean to use Gforth ... else you may have difficulties with bad examples or other Forth interpreters specific words not included in ANSI Forth nor gnuforth.

Answer (score 1):

The FORTH standard says that control structures (IF, ELSE, THEN; DO, LOOP; and so on) are for *compiled use* only, interactive use is an "ambiguous situation". Some implementations allow interactive use, but it is far from universal.